# How to add one more row and double of selected rows to the protected data using getRange() or getActiveRange() in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I manually select A41 to F80 and it is nicely protecting A41 to F80 using the following line of code.

However, I want to (i) add one more row to the protected data (A41 to F81) though I will select A41 to F80.

Also in another case I want to add double of selected rows plus one to the protected data (A41:F121) though I will select A41 to F80.

Probably `getActiveRange()` won't work, then I tried to use `getRange()` but can't solve it. Please help me to solve it.

```
var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().protect().setDescription(description);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You need to create a new range

- For this, use first the method [getHeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getheight) to retrieve the height of `activeRange`.
- Then, add `1` to it.
- Create a new range with the method [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- Whereby `row`, `column` and `numColumns` can be taken from `activeRange` - only the height is new.

Sample:

```
var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var height = activeRange.getHeight();
var newHeight = height + 1;
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var newRange = activeSheet.getRange(activeRange.getRow(), activeRange.getColumn(), newHeight, activeRange.getWidth());
var protection = newRange.protect().setDescription(description);
```